# User with offensive username and post needs nukes

Tags: support, status-completed

There's this user who needs nuking. [User link](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/41093). I hope I don't need to say why he needs to go. [Here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/38271/what-are-the-proper-settings-for-taking-low-light-action-pictures-using-nikon-d5/65233#65233)'s the link to the offencive post. (Yes, its the answer)

Comment: What about flagging the post with the custom flag?

Comment: @nicael Its already deleted!

Comment: That's not the problem, though. I've just flagged the deleted post. http://i.stack.imgur.com/vmG9X.png

Comment: @nicael That user has been around too long

Comment: Oh what now? He's back and suspended?